# External hard drive won't show certain files

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Recently I got a new external hard drive (Seagate, with 931 GB of free space). I plugged it in to my desktop and copied some files on to it (Where then I had 920 GB of free space). Then I plugged it in to my laptop and it isn't showing some of the files I copied. Furthermore, the disk showed 931 GB of free space again. What is going on?

I plugged it back in to my desktop computer and the files showed up there.

Windows 8 on Lenovo X1 Laptop
Windows 7 on Desktop

Comment: Please don't shoot me for this question as no offence is meant, but, are you sure you copied it? I mean, have you tried again to prove it's not copying across? Does the original machine still detect the files? Is it FAT or NTFS? What size were the files you copied?... More information is needed, [please edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/635787/edit)

Comment: When you plug it back into your desktop, do you see your files? Additionally, what OS does your laptop have? Mac's have a different file-system than Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that yes, when I plug it back in to my desktop I can see the files that I copied. Also I tried plugging it in to someone else's laptop to test it and the files showed up there too. My desktop runs windows 7, my laptop windows 8, and the other laptop I tested it on runs windows 8.

Comment: Does the external drive require power via USB?

Comment: If the drive is using NTFS it is possible for some User permissions to be hiding the files. Try removing all permissions from the files in the external harddrive on your desktop and then check whether you can see them again on the laptop.

Comment: This is the hard drive http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178104 It is powered through the same USB that it connects to the computer through

Comment: Did you format your drive as NTFS?

Comment: It is formatted as NFTS, I will try removing user permissions

Comment: Have you checked the Quota settings of the volume from the desktop?